# How to handle relative URL in apache HTTPClient

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using apache httpclient 4.5.3 to submit POST request to another different web page (say example.com). I am getting back the response using a custom response handler. The response page is handled as below:

```
    HttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy()).setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore).build();
HttpPost httpget = new HttpPost("http://www.example.com/post.php");
...
    String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler, context);
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println(responseBody);
    out.close();
```

The problem is when rendering the page, the relative URI in the html page (like /scripts/test.css) resulting in HTTP-404 for the obvious reason that this scripts do not exist in my tomcat.

How to handle this issue?

//SB

Answer (score 0):

The Apache HTTP Client is a HTTP Client it does not handle automatically
resources referenced within and HTML page. These referenced resources need to be fetched separately.

The Apache HTTP Client just simplifies dealing with the HTTP Protocol (and it's extensions) like Cookies, Caching, Keep Alive, ...

From your description it sounds like your trying deliver (parts) of an external Web Site from within you own tomcat.
Let's assume that there are no legal issues.

**You have different options:**

- use an IFrame to include the external content.
- rewrite the external HTML page to include only absolute URLs
- parse and rewrite the HTML page
- intercept the relative requests and treat them similar to HTML page
  i.e. fetch them from the external host and deliver the content so that it looks like they are hosted on your tomcat.